# Minkowski sum with 2D and 3D geometries

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, regions, computational-geometry, geometry

I have searched for this but the only questions I've found are [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/76452/how-do-i-do-the-minkowski-sum-of-two-sets/76462#76462), and [a more closely related one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87866/minkowski-sum-and-product-of-2d-regions).

How can I compute and plot the Minkowski sum of geometric entities in both 2D and 3D?

There are some demonstrations like [this one](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheMinkowskiSumOfADiskAndAPolygon/), [and this other one](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheMinkowskiSumOfTwoTriangles/), but they are **not generic**.

I'd like to do something like this with **any** geometry (or at least be *a little* generic...):

```
c = Circle[{0, 0}, 1];
l = Line[{{0, 0}, {3, 5}}];
a = MagicMinkowskiSum[{c, l}];
Show[{Graphics[c], Graphics[l], Graphics[a]}]

s = Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1];
r = Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {3, 5, 4}}];
b = MagicMinkowskiSum[{s, r}]; (* or MagicMinkowskiSum3D[...] *)
Show[{Graphics3D[s], Graphics3D[r], Graphics3D[b]}]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think seeing the Minkowski sum as a 2D/3D convolution of regions and using `ImplicitRegion` on the resulting polynomial inequalities could be an alley worth exploring to get you the generality you are looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found one way that works on a simple example, namely

```
region1 = Rectangle[]
region2 = Disk[{0,0},1/8]
```

The implementation looks like this:

```
MinkowskiSum[region1_, region2_, vars_] := Module[
  {region1membercond, region2membercond, d1, d2, d, tmpvars, joinedregionmembercond},
  {d1, d2} = RegionEmbeddingDimension /@ {region1, region2}; Assert[d1 == d2];
  d = d1; Assert[Length[vars] == d];
  tmpvars = Table[Unique["tmp"], {d}];
  region1membercond = RegionMember[region1, vars - tmpvars] /. _ \[Element] Reals -> True;
  region2membercond = RegionMember[region2,        tmpvars] /. _ \[Element] Reals -> True;
  joinedregionmembercond = Resolve[Exists[Evaluate@tmpvars, region1membercond \[And] region2membercond], Reals];
  ImplicitRegion[joinedregionmembercond, vars]
]
```

and

```
regionscombined = MinkowskiSum[region1, region2, {x, y}]
```

gives

```
ImplicitRegion[ x^2 + y^2 <= 1/64 || (x <= 1 && x >= 0 && y <= 1 && y >= 0) || (x <= 1 && x >= 0 && y^2 <= 1/64) || (x <= 1 && x >= 0 && y > 0 && -2 y + y^2 <= -(63/64)) || (x > 0 && -2 x + x^2 <= -(63/64) && y <= 1 && y >= 0) || (x^2 <= 1/64 && y <= 1 && y >= 0) || (x > 0 && -2 x + x^2 + y^2 <= -(63/64)) || (x > 0 && -2 x + x^2 - 2 y + y^2 <= -(127/64)) || (y > 0 && x^2 - 2 y + y^2 <= -63/64)), {x, y}]

RegionPlot[regionscombined]
```

[image: Minkowski sum of region1 and region2, looking like a rounded rectangle]

Here `Resolve` is doing the heavy lifting figuring out the correct inequalities that describe the combined region and eliminating the temporary 'integration variables' that were used in the `Exists` quantifier.

The first version i tried was based on `SignedRegionDistance` and using `Integrate` to do the convolution, but this took forever and `Integrate` never produced a result. The key insight was that we only ever need boolean conditions (namely that there exists an intemediate point `{u,v}` that is member of both regions) and not a full integration result with real values. This can be solved conveniently by putting our temporary integration variables (used in the convolution) into our existential quantifier and letting `Resolve` eliminate them. Then we are left with a condition on our original variables which we can give to `ImplicitRegion` and we're done.

The method depends on `RegionMember` returning an explicit expression that we can work with. I can imagine that for things like mesh regions this probably won't work where `RegionMemberFunction` stays unevaluated and only gives results for numeric values. Apart from that i think the method is pretty general!

## Examples in 2D and 3D

Now we can e.g. solve the original example problem:

```
region1 = Circle[{0, 0}, 1];
region2 = Line[{{0, 0}, {3, 5}}];
combinedregion = MinkowskiSum[region1, region2, {x, y}];
combinedregion = MapAt[FullSimplify, combinedregion, 1]
```

resulting in

```
ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 == 1 || ((5 x - 3 y)^2 <= 34 && (x^2 + y^2 < 1 || 0 < 3 x + 5 y <= 34 || 33 + (-6 + x) x + (-10 + y) y <= 0)), {x, y}]
```

We can plot the regions and get

```
RegionPlot[{combinedregion, region1, region2}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Minkowski sum from OP's example problem 1]

We can also solve the second example, which extends the idea to 3D:

```
region1 = Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1];
region2 = Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {3, 5, 4}}];
combinedregion = MinkowskiSum[region1, region2, {x, y, z}];
combinedregion = MapAt[FullSimplify, combinedregion, 1]
```

giving

```
ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1 || (41 x^2 + 25 y^2 + 34 z^2 <= 50 + 40 y z + 6 x (5 y + 4 z) && (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < 1 || 0 < 3 x + 5 y + 4 z <= 50 || 49 + (-6 + x) x + (-10 + y) y + (-8 + z) z <= 0)), {x, y, z}]
```

With `RegionPlot3D` we can also render a discretized version of the region

```
RegionPlot3D[combinedregion, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 40, PlotRange -> {{-1, 4}, {-1, 6}, {-1, 5}}]
```

[image: Second example (3D) from OP.]

Here is another example that shows the method working in 3D:

```
combinedregion3d = MinkowskiSum[Cuboid[], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1/8], {x, y, z}];
RegionPlot3D[combinedregion3d, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image: Minkowski sum in 3D]

Comment: Do you need to turn on `Asset` with `On[Assert]`?

Comment: Good question, actually `Assert` is just the first thing that came to my mind for input checking. What is the best canonical way to do input checking and throwing errors if something doesn't fit? I'm happy to update the answer to use something more appropriate.

Comment: I hope someone can answer. Actually I don't remember seeing `Assert` before, that's why I checked the doc.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use [`TransformedRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedRegion) with [`RegionProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionProduct). Here is a function that does this:

```
Options[MinkowskiSum] = Options[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion];

MinkowskiSum[r1_, r2_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{d1,d2,func,bounds},
    d1=RegionEmbeddingDimension[r1];
    d2=RegionEmbeddingDimension[r2];
    (
    func=Evaluate[Array[Slot, d1] + Array[Slot, d1, d1+1]]&;
    bounds=RegionBounds[r1]+RegionBounds[r2];
    Quiet[
        BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
            TransformedRegion[RegionProduct[r1, r2], func],
            bounds,
            opts
        ],
        BoundaryDiscretizeRegion::brepl
    ]
    ) /; d1===d2
]
```

Your examples:

```
MinkowskiSum[Circle[{0,0}, 1], Line[{{0,0},{3,5}}], Axes->True, ImageSize->200]
```

[image]

```
MinkowskiSum[
    Sphere[{0,0,0}, 1],
    Line[{{0,0,0},{3,5,4}}],
    Axes->True,
    ImageSize->200
]
```

[image]